# Set drawable opacity

Tags: android, opacity

How can i set the opacity of a `Drawable` object?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You can use Drawable's `setAlpha()` method. It takes an int from 0 to 255, 0 being fully transparent, and 255 being fully opaque.

See the developer reference [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/Drawable.html#setAlpha%28int%29).

Answer (score 0):

0 means fully transparent, and 255 means fully opaque:

```
(drawable).getBackground().setAlpha(int alpha);
```

Comment: Drawable doesn't have a getBackground() method